# Calloc & realloc: Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (normal)

Tags: c, free, realloc, calloc

I have a little piece of code (in C) where I'am allocating an array and scaning numbers in it. If the array is too small I'm reallocating memory for my array. Sometimes it works fine but sometimes it returns "Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (normal)."

Here is the code:

```
int *array;
int memory=0, i=0, scanreturn=0;
array = (int *)calloc(30, sizeof(int));
/*Allocating 30 ints*/
while ( scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF){
  if(i == (memory - 5)){
    /*There's only 5 ints left. Allocating 10 more*/
    memory = memory + 10;
    array = (realloc(array, memory * sizeof *array));
  }
  i++;
}
...
free(array);
```

I suppose it's cause freeing the memory at the end but I really don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: That's not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845). (You don't even consistently violate that guideline.)

Comment: In addition to @Deduplicator's comment, see [c-faq 7.7b What's wrong with casting `malloc`'s return value?](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: regarding this line: array = (int *)calloc(30, sizeof(int)); the code should always check the contents of array to assure that the calloc was successful I.E. contents not NULL

Comment: regarding this line: array = (realloc(array, memory * sizeof *array)); 1) there is an extra set of parens that should be removed. 2) the original variable pointer 'array' should NOT be used as the receiving variable, because if the realloc function fails, then the original pointer is lost.

Comment: this line: while ( scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF){ 1) the scanf, after the first, will probably fail as the intervening newline has not been consumed suggest the format string be " %d", notice leading space.  2) the returned value from scanf needs to be checked to assure that the input was successful

Comment: regarding this line: if(i == (memory - 5)){  i starts at 0 and increments and memory starts at 0 and is not modified unless this if evaluates to true, so this IF code block will never be entered.

Comment: if memory were initialized to 30 and used in the original calloc() then the code has some chance of working.  However, why alloc 10 more int sized entries when there are still 5 not yet used,  Better to check if i+1 == memory then memory+= 10;

Comment: this line: array = (realloc(array, memory * sizeof *array)); 1) is using 'memory' which at the initial pass through this code block is set to 10 (0+10) which is far smaller than the initial 30 allocation. 2) sizeof is a compile time operator, so knows nothing about the current size of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your posted code,

```
int *array;
int memory=0, i=0, scanreturn=0;
array = (int *)calloc(30, sizeof(int));
/*Allocating 30 ints*/
while ( scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF){

  // ***********************************************
  // This conditional will never be true since
  // memory has been initialized to 0.
  // ***********************************************
  if(i == (memory - 5)){
    /*There's only 5 ints left. Allocating 10 more*/
    memory = memory + 10;
    array = (realloc(array, memory * sizeof *array));
  }

  // ***********************************************
  // What happens when 1 == 30?
  // You start writing over out of bounds memory, leading to undefined behavior.
  // ***********************************************
  i++;
}
...
free(array);
```

If you initialize `memory` correctly, the purpose of using

```
  if(i == (memory - 5)){
```

would've been served. Change the line

```
int memory=0, i=0, scanreturn=0;
```

to

```
int memory=30, i=0, scanreturn=0;
```

to solve the problem.

Comment: It's perfectly clear what he wants to accomplish: to grow `array` as soon as he's close to running out of space. He just does it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Questions to ask yourself:

1) Since you have no error checking, it's hard to say whether any of your `alloc`'s are working

2) `i` and `memory` start as 0, when will `realloc` ever be called?

2a) if `realloc` isn't called, what happens when you get to the end of your original `alloc`?

P.S. Never cast the result of an `alloc` 
P.P.S. 
values of `i` 0, 1, 2, 3, ....
values of `memory` 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, .....
values of `memory - 5` -5, -5, -5, -5, .....
`if (i == (memory - 5))` 
`0 == -5` FALSE 
`1 == -5` FALSE 
`2 == -5` FALSE 
`3 == -5` FALSE 
......

As you can see, it will take a long time for this to not be FALSE

Answer (score 1):

With your starting conditions for i and memory, you never enter the if statement in the loop
 `if(i == (memory - 5))`, array is never reallocated, and when you scanf() into the array you are writing out of bounds. This is undefined behaviour and aparently you overwrite some internal data, because you get a warning when you call free().

Answer (score 1):

```
int *array;
int memory=0, i=0, scanreturn=0;
array = (int *)calloc(30, sizeof(int));
/*Allocating 30 ints*/
while ( scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF){
  if(i == (memory - 5)){
```

What have we here? How can this `if` *ever* trigger? `memory` is set to `0` and never modified and `i` starts at `0` and gets incremented with every iteration of the loop. So your loop compares:

```
 i == (memory - 5)  result
 0 == (0 - 5)        false
 1 == (0 - 5)        false
 2 == (0 - 5)        false
           ...
30 == (0 - 5)        false
31 == (0 - 5)        false
```

As a result, you never get into the code which attempts to grow the buffer and you end up with a buffer overflow. After that, you're in undefined behavior land and anything goes.

The obvious solution? Set `memory = 30` instead of `memory = 0`.

Also note that you never check the result of `calloc` or `realloc`. While it's extremely unlikely for  a memory operation to fail with modern operating systems, you should not just ignore the possibility of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up version of your code:

```
int memory=0, i=0;
array = calloc(30, sizeof(int));

while (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF) {
  if (i == (memory - 5)) {
    memory = memory + 10;
    array = realloc(array, memory * sizeof *array);
  }
  i++;
}
```

You need to initialize `memory = 30`. With `memory = 0`, your comparison will become `if (i == -5)...`, and `realloc()` will never be called.

You should also check the return value of `calloc()` and `realloc()` in case the allocations fail.